# PDO and prepared statements

Tags: pdo

I'm trying to implement this query:

```
SELECT AVG(timediff(end, start)) AS avg_in FROM phone_call
WHERE user_id=2
AND direction = 'o'
AND DATE(start) = DATE('2013-11-04 17:11:37')
```

using PDO with PHP. Could you provide some advice on how to do this. Ive tried:

```
$uid = 2; $direction='o'; $date='2013-11-04 17:11:37';


$q = "SELECT AVG(timediff(end, start)) AS avg_in FROM phone_call
                WHERE user_id = ?
                AND direction = ?
                AND DATE(start) = DATE(?))";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($q);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT, 5);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $direction, PDO::PARAM_STR, 1);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $date, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //$result = round($result,2);

        return $result;
```

but this fails.

edit:

client code:

```
$a = $call_log->getAvCallIn(2,'o','2013-11-04 17:11:37'); //
print '<pre>';print_r($a);
```

nothing get printed to the screen!

I suspect it's the

```
AND DATE(start) = DATE(?))
```

part of the query that is faulty?

Comment: _“but this fails”_ – _where_ /with what error?

Comment: I had an extranous bracket, syntax error. doh